# Is there any language where names can include space characters?

Tags: programming-languages, compiler-theory

Is there any programming language that allows Names to include white spaces ? (By names, I intend variables, methods, field, etc.)

Comment: just curious... why do want it?

Comment: If you're interested in adding more whitespace to your source code, check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29

Comment: I was going to mention Whitespace, but it doesn't look like it has any names.  Prolog is another one that allows a quoted string like 'this that' to be used in the same way as identifiers, as people have already noted for Ruby, SQL, and more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala does allow whitespace characters in identifier names (but for that to be possible, you need to surround the identifiers with pair of backticks).

Example (executed at Scala REPL):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val `lol! this works! :-D` = 4
lol! this works! :-D: Int = 4

scala> val `omg!!!` = 4
omg!!!: Int = 4

scala> `omg!!!` + `lol! this works! :-D`
res0: Int = 8
```

Answer (score 5):

In SQL you can have spaces and other non-identifier characters in field names and such. You just have to quote them like `[field name]` or `"field name"`.

Comment: I've only ever seen the square-bracket convention in Microsoft products. Are there any others that use it or do they mostly use the double-quotes I see more often?

Comment: The quotes are ANSI standard SQL, but I believe the brackets were inherited from Sybase. That's why SQL Server uses them but Access doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Common Lisp can do it with variables, if you surround the variable name with pipes (|):

```
CL-USER> (setf |hello world| 42)
42
CL-USER> |hello world|
42
```

Worth noting is that "piped" variable names also are case sensitive (which variable names normally aren't in CL).

```
CL-USER> |Hello World|
The variable |Hello World| is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]
CL-USER> (setf hello-world 99)
99
CL-USER> hello-world
99
CL-USER> HeLlO-WoRlD
99
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP can: http://blog.riff.org/2008_05_11_spaces_php_variable_names

Perl also:

```
${'some var'} = 42;
print ${'some var'}, "\n";

${'my method'} = sub {
  print "method called\n";
};

&${'my method'};
```

Answer (score 3):

A more recent innovation and experimental web script (sub)type of JavaScript: https://github.com/featurist/pogoscript/wiki

```
wind speed = 25
average temperature = 32
```

becomes

```
windSpeed = 25
averageTemperature = 32
```

Behind the screens. Also flexible rules on positioning of return variables so you can do:

```
y = compute some value from (z) and return it
md5 hash (read all text from file "sample.txt")
```

Becomes:

```
var y;
y = computeSomeValueFromAndReturnIt(z);
md5Hash(readAllTextFromFile("sample.txt"));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby you can have symbols that are named as `:"this has a space"` but it is enclosed in double-quotes so I'm not sure if you count that.

If other languages allowed whitespace as a valid character in symbol names, then you would have to use some other character to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with spaces in variable names is that it's subject to interpretation since whitespace normally means "ok, end of the current token, starting another."  Exceptions to this rule must have some special indicator such as quotation marks in a string ("This is a test").

Answer (score 1):

Our [PARLANSE](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/parlanse/index.html) parallel programming language is one such.  In fact, it allows any character in identifiers, although many of them, including spaces, have to be escaped (preceded by ~) to be included in the name.   Here's an example:

```
         ~'Buffer~ Marker~'
```

This is used to let PARLANSE easily refer to arbitrary symbols from *other* languages (in particular, from EBNFs taken from arbitrary reference documents, where we can't control the punctuation used).

We don't use this feature a lot, but when it is needed it means we can stay true to tokens from other documents.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find esoteric languages that don't separate expression elements with whitespaces on this website: http://99-bottles-of-beer.net

For example... [whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/) :D

Answer (score 0):

Some dialects of SQL allow databases, tables, and fields to have spaces in their names.

For example, in SQL Server, you can refer to a table with a space in its name, either by putting the table name in `[square brackets]` or (depending on connection options) in `"double quotes"`.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be much problems creating such languages supporting whitespaces in identifiers, as long as there are enough separating tokens which say the parser where the identifiers end (such as operators, braces, commas and the infamous semicolon). It just doesn't improve the readability of the source code much.