# Problem with space in a Scala class setter

Tags: scala

I am a Scala newbie and one thing that I find very strange is the error

> ";" or new line expected

for example the class Point definition in [Tour of scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html) section *Private Members and Getter/Setter Syntax*
if I write the code like this

```
def x_ = (newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

I will get the *; or new line expected* and it does not recognise newLine . *Note the space after x_*. and if I write it without the space like this

```
def x_= (newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

the mentioned errors disappear?!

Why is that? is this something to do with the scala language or is it to do with intellij ide. If it has something to do with the language then why don't I get the error in this definition

```
def x = _x
```

Comment: `def x = _x` is creating a **method** called `x` that when called returns the value of `_x` - `def x_ =` is trying to create a method whose name is `x_ =` which is not valid syntax, if you want it to be named like that you need to use ` as shown by Mario. - Both are two completely different things so I really do not understand why they confuse you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (as you have discovered) is that `_=` is treated specially at the end of a method name. (See [the spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers))

So this is valid

```
def x_= (newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

but this is not

```
def x= (newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

and neither is this

```
def x_=x (newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

In fact section 1.1 of the spec says that there can be any `op` after an `_`, so these are also valid:

```
def x_#(newValue : Int): Unit = {}
def x_+-*/(newValue : Int): Unit = {}
def x_???(newValue : Int): Unit = {}
```

Answer (score 4):

Whitespace is [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214532/5205022) allowed in identifiers, so

```
def x_ = = 42
```

is not allowed for the same reason why

```
def hello_ world = 42
```

is not allowed. If you want whitespace in an identifier, then surround it with backquotes

```
scala> def `x_ =` = 42
def x_$u0020$eq: Int

scala> `x_ =`
val res0: Int = 42

scala> def `hello_ world` = 42
def hello_$u0020world: Int

scala> `hello_ world`
val res1: Int = 42
```

The identifier `x_=` has no whitespace so the following is legal

```
scala> def x_= = 42
def x_$eq: Int

scala> x_=
val res2: Int = 42
```

Not how the two `=` in `def x_= = 42` are semantically different

```
def x_=               = 42
      |               |   
part of identifier   body follows
```

Comment: thanks but that was not what I was looking for, as far as I know no programming language allows the use of space in identifier. But I did find my answer in scala specifications see https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html. Setter functions in a class are declared in that manner

Comment: The answer to why this particular method name is valid is [here](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers)